# How can I specify a timezone to use for a single ActiveRecord create or update operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I know I can do this:

```
Time.use_zone("St. Petersburg"){
  Foo.create!(
    topic: "foo", begins_at: "2015-06-01", ends_at: "2015-06-02"
  )
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Something like:

```
Foo.create!(
  topic: "foo", begins_at: "2015-06-01", ends_at: "2015-06-02",
  timezone: "St. Petersburg"
)
```

Comment: Why would you want the timestamps in local time? Its going to make any querying or comparison very complicated.

Comment: The `*_at` columns are postgres's `timetamp without time zone`. All data for all datetime columns for all tables in my app is UTC, including in this case. The data provided by the user is in the user's timezone. So in the first code example above, the user's submitted data is effectively converted to UTC before being written to the db.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
Foo.create!(
  topic: "foo", 
  begins_at: DateTime.parse("2015-06-01").in_time_zone('St. Petersburg'), 
  ends_at:   DateTime.parse("2015-06-02").in_time_zone('St. Petersburg')
)
```

Comment: Problem with that is there isn't an easy way to grab the datetime from what the user submits, because the form submits it as a bunch of independent integers (year, month, day, ...). So I would have to assemble them together by hand and miss out on activerecord convenience. I suppose another approach would be `f = Foo.new(...); f.begins_at = f.begins_at.in_time_zone(...); f.save`